# Graphics card causing splash screen to stay

Tags: amd-radeon, pci-express, nvidia-geforce

I have a GTX 650 ti, and it recently had its drivers crash. After uninstalling and re-installing it with failure, it kept crashing. I formatted my drive using a spare Radeon 6770 I have. After installing 8.1, I switched graphics cards out before installing any drivers. The graphics card on my PCIE x16 slot started to become buggy and caused my splash screen to stay there forever. I switched it to the other slot thats not 16x, and it booted perfectly. I am unsure what to do with the 16x slot. Any suggestions?